# How to speed up comparison of subsets of two matrices in R

Tags: r, matrix, vectorization

I have a matrix `R`, say `20x20`, and a matrix `s_mat`, say `400x2`. I want to compare (stored in `h.help`) each sub-vector of size `2x1` of matrix `R` to each row of `s_mat`.  Using for loops, as in the code below, takes too long. Is there any way I can avoid these for loops? Because for larger matrices it takes too long. Many thanks!

```
library(gtools)
R=matrix(sample(1:20,400, replace=TRUE), ncol=20, nrow=20)
l=2
s_mat = permutations(nrow(R), l, repeats.allowed=TRUE) 
F = numeric()
F_perm = data.frame(matrix(NA,ncol=nrow(R)^l,nrow=nrow(R)-l+1)) 
  for (perm in 1:nrow(s_mat))
  {
    s = s_mat[perm,]
    for (k in 0:(nrow(R)-l))  
    {
      h = rep (TRUE, ncol(R)) 
      for (j in 1:ncol(R))   
      {
        h.help = R[(k+1):(k+l),j] <= s
        if (sum(h.help)!=l) h[j]=FALSE
      } 
      F[k+1] = sum(h)/ncol(R)
    }
    F_perm[perm] = F
  }
```

Comment: I've updated the code. I'm using `h` after the most inner loop. My required output is the data.frame `F_perm`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will do the job:

```
set.seed(1L);
NV <- 20L; R.NR <- 20L; R.NC <- 20L; NP <- 2L;
R <- matrix(sample(NV,R.NR*R.NC,T),R.NR);
s_mat <- unname(as.matrix(do.call(expand.grid,rep(list(seq_len(NV)),NP))));
F_perm <- matrix(NA_real_,R.NR-NP+1L,nrow(s_mat));
for (sri in seq_len(nrow(s_mat))) {
    s <- s_mat[sri,];
    F_perm[,sri] <- rowSums(Reduce(`&`,Map(function(e,i) R[i:(nrow(R)-length(s)+i),]<=e,s,seq_along(s))))/ncol(R);
}; ## end for
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @bgoldst, brilliant, this is much faster!! I'm not sure how to incorporate calculation of `F` and `F_perm` (see my updated my code). Can you please help?

Comment: Thanks, strangely, the output of my `F_perm` and your `F_perm` are not identical. But I don't see the problem. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, this is just due to the random sampling, so everything works, thank you so much!!!